# Pandas Merge duplicate index into single index

Tags: pandas

I have a simple data frame like this:

```
d1={'a':{'1998-01-01':10}}
d2={'b':{'1998-01-01':3}}

df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d1)
df=df.append(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d2))
df.index=pd.to_datetime(df.index)

             a   b
1998-01-01  10 NaN
1998-01-01 NaN   3
```

I would like to have

```
             a   b
1998-01-01  10   3
```

Since 1998-01-01 share the index

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Or you can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by `index` different way - with parameter `level=0` with [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html):

```
print df.groupby(level=0).sum()

             a  b
1998-01-01  10  3
```

Or better:

```
print df.sum(level=0)
```

Comment: you are creating 2 different dataframes. I have only a single one. I gave the code to show how to create my data. is there another way?

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand your question. Another answer is the best solution.

Comment: @jezrael Would you please be able to explain what `level=0` means? I've checked to docs but I'm still in the dark.

Comment: @pfabri Check MultiIndex, it means first or second level there, if no MultiIndex, then Index working same like first level of MultiIndex.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively you can try this (with your original data frame):

```
print(df)
print(df.groupby(df.index).sum())
```

Output:

```
             a   b
1998-01-01  10 NaN
1998-01-01 NaN   3
             a  b
1998-01-01  10  3
```